# Why authorization failed after successful authentication

Tags: oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2, cas

I configured CAS server with OAuth2.0 protocol (authorization code grant type) based on post https://apereo.github.io/2019/02/19/cas61-as-oauth-authz-server/

my server configuration (application.yml)

```
cas:
  server:
    name: https://casoauth.example.org:8443
    prefix: ${cas.server.name}/cas
  authn:
    accept:
      users: casuser::demo
    oauth:
      refreshToken:
        timeToKillInSeconds: 2592000
      code:
        timeToKillInSeconds: 14400
        numberOfUses: 10
      accessToken:
        timeToKillInSeconds: 14400
        maxTimeToLiveInSeconds: 28800
      grants:
        resourceOwner:
          requireServiceHeader: true
      userProfileViewType: FLAT
  ticket:
    tgt:
      maxTimeToLiveInSeconds: 28800
      timeToKillInSeconds: 14400
    st:
      timeToKillInSeconds: 14400
  serviceRegistry:
    json:
      location: classpath:/services
    initFromJson: true
logging:
  config: file:/etc/cas/config/log4j2.xml
  level:
    org:
      apereo:
        cas: DEBUG
```

json for register app

```
{
  "@class" : "org.apereo.cas.support.oauth.services.OAuthRegisteredService",
  "clientId": "client1",
  "clientSecret": "password1",
  "serviceId": "^https://casoauth.example.org:9999/.*",
  "name": "OAuthService",
  "id": 1000,
  "bypassApprovalPrompt": false,
  "supportedGrantTypes": [ "java.util.HashSet", [ "authorization_code" ] ],
  "supportedResponseTypes": [ "java.util.HashSet", [ "code" ] ]
}
```

app configuration

```
debug: true
server:
  port: 9999
  ssl:
    keyStore: file:/etc/cas/thekeystore
    keyStorePassword: changeit
    keyPassword: changeit

security:
  user:
    password: user
  ignored: /,/favicon.ico,/index.html,/home.html,/dashboard.html,/js/**,/css/**,/webjars/**
  sessions: ALWAYS
  oauth2:
    sso:
      loginPath: /dashboard/login
management:
  security:
    role: HERO

logging:
  level:
    org.springframework: INFO
    com.netflix.discovery: 'OFF'

---
spring:
  profiles: cas
security:
  oauth2:
    client:
      clientId: client1
      clientSecret: password1
      accessTokenUri: https://casoauth.example.org:8443/cas/oauth2.0/accessToken
      userAuthorizationUri: https://casoauth.example.org:8443/cas/oauth2.0/authorize
      clientAuthenticationScheme: form
    resource:
      userInfoUri: https://casoauth.example.org:8443/cas/oauth2.0/profile
      preferTokenInfo: false
```

After authentication on CAS server I get

Whitelabel Error Page

This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Tue Jun 04 17:10:41 CEST 2019
There was an unexpected error (type=Unauthorized, status=401).
Authentication Failed: Could not obtain access token

URL https://casoauth.example.org:9999/dashboard/login?code=OC-1-lu5Hlcg2l3E4S5B68fs0-P-47tkh-4gR&state=ef17Ee

Any ideas what is wrong?

Comment: `https://casoauth.example.org:8443/cas/oauth2.0/accessToken` and `https://casoauth.example.org:9999` seems to not be the same, the port seems to be incorrect. See if changing the port fix this, cheers.

Comment: On 8443 is running CAS server and on 9999 is running Client app. I thing that this config is ok

Comment: oic, my mistakes

Comment: Maybe is jdk version? They specifically said need JDK11 for SSO, and JDK8 for the app

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem. You should add your certificate to trusted certificate and problem will solve.